# Delete Database and ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have problem delete `DataBase` using `ListView`. I can delete the `DataBase`, but when I open again `ListView` I get an error. I got two class which is UserList.class and MySQLiteHelpre.class. In my UserList.class, I extend it to `Activity` and add method `onItemLongClick`.

```
06-03 09:13:43.880  18615-18615/com.sinergi.los.activity E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.sinergi.los.activity, PID: 18615
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sinergi.los.activity/com.sinergi.los.activity.UserList}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2603)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5752)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
        at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getLong(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:74)
        at com.sinergi.los.dao.InfoPokokDao.cursorToInfoPokok(InfoPokokDao.java:75)
        at com.sinergi.los.dao.InfoPokokDao.getById(InfoPokokDao.java:174)
        at com.sinergi.los.dao.PermohonanKreditDao.cursorToFormPK(PermohonanKreditDao.java:56)
        at com.sinergi.los.dao.PermohonanKreditDao.getAllFormPK(PermohonanKreditDao.java:90)
        at com.sinergi.los.activity.UserList.onCreate(UserList.java:102)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5600)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2508)
```

This my `ListView` code

```
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_row_list, userList);

    mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    mainListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

            final AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(UserList.this);
            b.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
            b.setMessage("Ingin menghapus data?");
            b.setPositiveButton("Ya",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                            IDTable = IDList.get(position);

                            MySQLiteHelper db=new MySQLiteHelper(getApplicationContext());
                            db.delete("" + IDTable);
                            userList.remove(position);
                            UserList.this.listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }
                    });
            b.setNegativeButton("Tidak",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            b.show();
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

This my delete code in `dbHelper`

```
public void delete(String id)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_INFO_POKOK, COLUMN_ID + "=?", new String[]{id});
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: no, just row by id selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root cause here:

```
Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

Your table in database is empty (as the result, the cursor is empty), but you are trying to get something in it. The solution is always check `cursor.moveToFirst()` before you query anything.

```
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    // cursor.getLong...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help.

```
 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
 Cursor c = db.getsavedcontacts();
        c.moveToPosition(position);// adapter position
        String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_ID));

  db.deleteRow(Long.parseLong(id));//remove entry from database according to rowID
  arr.remove(info.position); //remove entry from arrayadapter, will remove entry from listview
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  c.close();
```